# Remove all sub arrays for multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

What is a simple mode, in PHP, to remove all the sub arrays of a multidimensional array? What I want is to remove all the sub arrays but the top one...

Thanks,
titel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $k => $a) {
    if (is_array($a)) { unset($array[$k]); }
}
```

Like this?

Answer (score 2):

```
function FlattenCallback($Value) { return !is_array($Value); }

$OneDimension = array_filter($MultiDimension, 'FlattenCallback');
```